# How to find out if a homebrew package is optimised for apple M1

Tags: package, homebrew, package-managers, homebrew-cask, apple-m1

How to find out if a brew or cask package is optimised for apple M1. There doesn't seem to be any info on the respective package pages.

Any links of a regularly updated list of native packages also would be very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ and search and click on the package you want to check. There you will find 
`Bottle (binary package) installation support provided for macOS releases:` 
Check Apple silicon ( if it is supported Big Sur will be written ).

Comment: Nice, but do you know if it's doable from the commandline?
It would be nice if it were part of the `brew info` output.

Comment: I don't think it provides the information right now, although you can even check using activity monitor for any app.